# How to launch two jobs simultaneously after the execution of one Job in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a Main Pentaho job that has three jobs Job1, Job2 and Job3 in it. I want to execute Job2 and Job3 as soon as Job1 is finished. I tried to do it, but Pentaho executes Job2 first and then Job3 in the last.

Is there any way that both the jobs are launched at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on Job 1 and select "Run Next Entries in Parallel". A warning dialog box will appear. Be sure to pay attention to what it says and think about the possible implications. I've been bitten by that more than once.

Should look something like this:

[image]